# How to use IOPMAssertionCreateWithName in swift

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift

I want my app do something when user want to sleep the os x, and then continue sleep. I found a way just prevent the system from sleeping in oc, but when I use swift rewrite the code, the xcode can't recognize the kIOPMAssertionTypeNoDisplaySleep parameter. How can I use it?

```
IOPMAssertionID assertionID;
IOReturn success = IOPMAssertionCreateWithName(kIOPMAssertionTypeNoDisplaySleep, 
                                    kIOPMAssertionLevelOn, reasonForActivity, &assertionID); 
if (success == kIOReturnSuccess)
{

    //Add the work you need to do without 
    //  the system sleeping here.

    success = IOPMAssertionRelease(assertionID);
    //The system will be able to sleep again. 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kIOPMAssertionTypeNoDisplaySleep` is defined in  IOPMLib.h as

```
/*!
 * @define          kIOPMAssertionTypeNoDisplaySleep
 * @deprecated      Deprecated in 10.7.
 * @abstract        Please use assertion type <code>@link kIOPMAssertPreventUserIdleDisplaySleep@/link</code> instead.
 */
#define kIOPMAssertionTypeNoDisplaySleep   CFSTR("NoDisplaySleepAssertion")
```

and a `CFSTR()` definition is not imported to Swift. As a workaround, you can
define the constant as

```
let kIOPMAssertionTypeNoDisplaySleep = "NoDisplaySleepAssertion" as CFString
```

However, due to the deprecation notice, you probably should use

```
let kIOPMAssertPreventUserIdleDisplaySleep = "PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep" as CFString
```

instead:

```
import IOKit.pwr_mgt

var assertionID : IOPMAssertionID = IOPMAssertionID(0)
let success = IOPMAssertionCreateWithName(kIOPMAssertPreventUserIdleDisplaySleep,
                IOPMAssertionLevel(kIOPMAssertionLevelOn),
                reasonForActivity,
                &assertionID)
if success == kIOReturnSuccess {
    // ...
    IOPMAssertionRelease(assertionID)
}
```

Comment: Your code work well, thank you very much. Another question, Where should I put those code ? In which function? I'm new in cocoa.

Comment: @cck: I can't help you with that. I have just translated your code from.

Comment: Worth noting you need to `import IOKit.pwr_mgt`

Comment: @RobKeniger: Indeed, I have added it to the code. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

As it's not been ported across to swift yet, I suggest keeping it in Obj-C and use a bridging header between Obj-C and Swift.